# Finding a power I should raising probabilities so that the sum equals something

Tags: probability

Given a list of probabilities $p_1, ..., p_n,\ (p_1 +\cdots + p_n = 1),$ is there an analytical solution to find a power $x$ such that

$p_1^x + ... + p_n^x = q,$ where $q$ is some arbitrary real number?

I am able to find numerical solutions to this using optimisation in Python (Nelder-Mead) but I'm wondering if there's a faster analytical solution.

Comment: I doubt there's an analytical solution. Since the function increases monotonically with $x$ bisection should work - no need for the power of Nelder-Mead. That might be faster numerically.

Comment: I don't think there is an analytic solution to this problem but finding the numeric solution should be very fast. So if your numeric solver is slow I would recommend looking for a different numeric solver.

Comment: According to https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/plain/questionCorner/transsol.html, "there is no general formula for expressing the solution to the equation $a^x + b^x = c$ as a combination of elementary functions of $a$, $b$, and $c$."

Given that $a^x + b^x = c$ is similar to your problem, I don't think there is any analytic solution to your problem, except in special cases like $p_i = p_j$ for all $i, j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ we can simplify $p_1^x + \cdots + p_n^x = q$ to $n\cdot p_1^x = q$